# Effect of zeroes on shape of frequency response

Tags: transfer-function

For a System to be stable the poles have to be on the Left half of the s plane. But what is the significance of zeroes? Does it control the system in anyway? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, poles are what generally create an under-damped system. Here is a picture I drew for another question: -

[image]

If you looked at the lower left hand picture I've drawn the pole zero diagram in a way that shows the equivalent bode plot view. If the pole in that picture moved from left to right, the bode plot peak would increase and when the pole is right on the jw line the bode plot peak becomes infinity and instability is knocking at the door.

A zero anywhere is going to reduce any peak in the bode plot: -

- It can reduce the bode plot amplitude to zero at high frequencies creating a low pass filter,
- It can reduce the bode plot amplitude to zero at low frequencies (high pass filter) or
- Somewhere in between a notch filter is produced.

To add a little more weight if you had the following transfer function: -

\$\dfrac{s + A}{s + B}\$

Clearly there is a zero at -A and a pole at -B. If they are both coincident, in this simple example they will cancel hence, a zero can bring about stabilization.

Answer (score 2):

*But what is the significance of zeroes? Does it control the system in anyway?*

Yes - of course.

If the transfer function H(s)=N(s)/D(s) has a numerator N(s) that consists of a polynominal in s the roots of N(s)=0 are the zeros z of the transfer function. In this case, the polynominal can be written as products of expressions like (s+z) and/or (s-z). From this you can derive that the magnitude of the whole transfer function will be **enhanced** for for s>z.

The BODE diagram, which is created based on the asymptotic response lines, does reflect these zeros as follows: At the zero frequency z the slope of the asymptotics changes by +20dB/dec.

For example, a -20dB/dec line will change to a horizontal asymptotic at this frequency; a horizontal line will change the slope to +20dB/dec. In this context, it is important to note that also the PHASE shift will be enhanced (rising phase).

Very often, this is the reason for introducing zeros (improving stability margin).

(This behaviour is "dual" to the influence of the poles which cause a slope change of -20dB/dec.)